# Remove an HTML element depending by it's deep via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, limit, deep-linking

I have `nested lists` in my HTML page, these lists are managed by a jQuery code which give to the user the interaction of adding rows and children to the list nodes. Every list can contain a `div` used to add a new list as child.
My problem is I would like to add a dynamic limiter to the deep of the elements I can create:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><div class="add-child"></div></li>
            <li><div class="add-child"></div></li>
            <li><div class="add-row"></div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><div class="add-child"></div></li>
    <li><div class="add-child"></div></li>
    <li><div class="add-row"></div></li>
</ul>
```

The deep could change in the future, I know I can simply use a static selector like this if I want to work with `a max of 3 levels of deepness`:

```
$('li li li .add-child').remove();
```

But I would like a dynamic solution to set the deep via PHP and then limit it via jQuery, how could be my approach to this?

Comment: The jQuery code that adds the nested UL has to check the depth, and only continue if the limit hasn't been reached. Is that jQuery code your own code, or are you using a third-party plug-in?

Comment: It's just code for one page only, so I decided to not develop a plug-in for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
$( '.add-child' ).each( function() {
    if( $( this ).parents( 'li' ).length > someDepthSetByPHP )
    {
        $( this ).remove();
    }
} );
```

[*jsfiddle example*](http://jsfiddle.net/KBMSD/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.add-child')
    .filter(function(){
        return $(this).parents('li').length > 2;
    })
    .remove();
```

I know, you said you don't need a plugin, but I couldn't resist :D

```
$.fn.filterIfHasNParents = function(n, selector){
    var depth = n || 1;
    return $(this).filter(function(){
        return $(this).parents(selector || '').length > depth - 1;
    });
}
```

And then use it as :

```
$('.add-child').filterIfHasNParents(3, 'li').remove();
```